# When a user right clicks a <Link> on a Gatsby site, then selects "Open In New Tab", how can I ensure the link opens correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, hyperlink, gatsby

I have a Gatsby site using Gatsby Links to internal pages which work fine when you left click. However, in my client's environment when you right click the link then select 'open link in new tab' a new tab opens with a 404 error.

I can't recreate this on localhost or Netlify, and my client doesn't know anything about the hosting service they're using. I have a prefix path:

```
  pathPrefix: `/about/sites/default/files/etc/2019`, ...
```

and my Links are formatted like this:

```
<Link to="/downloads">...
```

In an email I was forwarded I got this clue:

" When you click that link you will notice that the '.html' extension disappears. So, whenever you try to open a link in a new tab it breaks, as well as when you click on the company logo at the top.

It should continue to include the '.html' at the end of the url like last year's links to prevent it from breaking like,
https://www.company.com/about/sites/default/files/etc/2018/index.html
https://www.company.com/about/sites/default/files/etc/2018/pageTwo.html "

The company logo is an `<a>` link with the href= https://www.company.com/about/.

It sounds like a solution might be adding .html to the file names? Has anyone encountered this issue before? I have no way to test or recreate the issue, and the customer expects it to be solved the first time, so I don't mind doing a lot of work for a guaranteed solution.

Comment: Are you saying you want to add `.html`? or `.html` not working? Single Page Application = clue is in the name has only one `.html` file which in the root. Then application takes care of routing. However server need to be configured to handle these routes to tell application how to load. So issue could be there OR it could be that routing in your application doesn't work properly

Comment: This is probably misconfiguration of the server where it just doesn't handle routes properly. You should definitely provide more details